# Estoy desarrollando un query tengo 2 columnas (MONTO) y (DEBCRE). quiero sustituir el campo NULL por cero. utilizo ISNULL y nada

Tags: sql

SELECT
(SELECT ISNULL( A.[MONTO], 0) WHERE A.[DEBCRE] IN ('0')) AS DEBITO,
(SELECT ISNULL( A.[MONTO], 0) WHERE A.[DEBCRE] IN ('5')) AS CREDITO
FROM [BDSERVER].[dbo].[REPUESTOS] A[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Como es imagen y no código lo que pusiste* te comento; su debe ser de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT
 ISNULL((Tu subquery), 0) as DEBITO,
 ISNULL((Tu subquery), 0) as CREDITO
FROM 
 LaReferenciaQueTienes
```

Debes evaluar lo que resulta del SubQuery ya su resultado es NULL.

Comment: Me funciono el Query, Estoy muy agradecido con Usted muchas Gracias